# Using interface's properties in TypeScript generics?

Tags: typescript, generics, redux

I'm trying to create a helper generic `actionCreator` function to avoid actionCreator-type functions for each of my actions:

```
interface Response {
    readonly value: 'A' | 'B';
}

enum ActionTypes {
    created = 'ns/created',
    deleted = 'ns/deleted',
}

interface Created {
    readonly type: ActionTypes.created;
    readonly payload: Response;
}

interface Deleted {
    readonly type: ActionTypes.deleted;
}

type Action = Created | Deleted;

// actionCreator = (type, payload) => ({type, payload});
// actionCreator(ActionTypes.created, response);
// actionCreator(ActionTypes.deleted);
```

Is it possible to tell TS that `actionCreator` should not just return a string and an optional payload object but to be aware of `type Action`  to check type and payload pairs?
Something like `function actionCreator<T>(type: T.type, payload: T.payload)` which is not valid TS.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All of the following assumes you have more than just two types of action.  If you really have just two, then use function overloads and be done with it:

```
function actionCreator(type: ActionTypes.created, payload: Response): Created;
function actionCreator(type: ActionTypes.deleted): Deleted;
function actionCreator(type: any, payload?: any) {
  return (typeof payload === 'undefined') ? { type } : { type, payload }
}
```

For more general stuff, read on:

---

Once the [conditional types](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/pull/21316) feature lands in TypeScript 2.8 (expected to be released sometime in Mar 2018, you can try it now with `typescript@next`) you will be able to specify a function that behaves as (I think) you want without touching your existing code, like this:

```
// If K is a key of T, return T[K].  Otherwise, return R
type MaybePropType<T, K extends string, R=never> = K extends keyof T ? T[K] : R

// Given K, one of the "type" properties of the Action union,
// produce the constituent of Action union whose type is K.  So:
// ActionFromType<ActionTypes.created> is Created, and
// ActionFromType<ActionTypes.deleted> is Deleted.
type ActionFromType<K extends Action['type'], AA = Action>
  = AA extends infer A
  ? MaybePropType<AA, 'type'> extends K ? AA : never
  : never

// The one-argument actionCreator() call accepts an element of ActionTypes
// corresponding to an Action with no payload, and produces an Action of that type.
function actionCreator<
  T extends ActionTypes & ('payload' extends keyof ActionFromType<T> ? never : {})
  >(type: T): ActionFromType<T>;

// The two-argument actionCreator() call accepts an element from ActionTypes
// corresponding to an Action with a payload, and a value of the payload type,
// and produces an Action of that type.
function actionCreator<
  T extends ActionTypes & ('payload' extends keyof ActionFromType<T> ? {} : never)
  >(type: T, payload: MaybePropType<ActionFromType<T>, 'payload'>): ActionFromType<T>;

// The implementation of actionCreator() creates a one-or-two-property
// value from its arguments.  Note that this implementation won't be right
// if you ever add new Action types that require more properties
function actionCreator(type: any, payload?: any) {
  return (typeof payload === 'undefined') ? { type } : { type, payload }
}
```

Here's how it works:

```
declare const resp: Response;

// no errors
const created = actionCreator(ActionTypes.created, resp); // Created
const deleted = actionCreator(ActionTypes.deleted); // Deleted

// errors
const badCreated = actionCreator(ActionTypes.created); // missing payload
const badDeleted = actionCreator(ActionTypes.deleted, "payload?!"); // unexpected payload
const badDeleted2 = actionCreator('ns/deleted'); // not typed as an enum
```

That's a lot of type juggling, and some of the error messages will be cryptic, and it depends on a very new feature.

---

If you don't mind changing your code around, you can get something that works with TypeScript 2.7 and where `actionCreator()` is easier to reason about... but the boilerplate before it might be a bit daunting:

```
// create a mapping from action type to payload type
type ActionPayloads = {
  'ns/created': Response
}
// create a list of actions with no payloads
type ActionsWithoutPayloads = 'ns/deleted';

// this is a helper type whose keys are the ActionTypes
// and whose values represent the part of the Action without the type
// so, just {} for a payloadless type, and {readonly payload: P} for
// a payloaded type
type ActionMap = { [K in ActionsWithoutPayloads]: {} } &
  { [K in keyof ActionPayloads]: { readonly payload: ActionPayloads[K] } }

// this is a helper function which makes sure we define ActionTypes
// correctly
const keysOfActionMap = <T extends { [k: string]: keyof ActionMap }>(x: T) => x;

// now we have ActionTypes.  It is a plain object, not an enum, 
// but it behaves similarly
const ActionTypes = keysOfActionMap({
  created: 'ns/created',
  deleted: 'ns/deleted'
});

// some helper type functions
type IntersectionToObject<T> = { [K in keyof T]: T[K] }
type ValueOf<T> = T[keyof T];

// extract Action from previous stuff.  
// Action by itself is a union of actions from before, while
// Action<K> is the action corresponding to K from ActionTypes.
type Action<K extends keyof ActionMap = keyof ActionMap> =
  ValueOf<{
    [P in K]: IntersectionToObject<{ readonly type: P } & ActionMap[P]>
  }>

// if you need names for Created and Deleted:    
type Created = Action<typeof ActionTypes.created>;
type Deleted = Action<typeof ActionTypes.deleted>;
```

Finally here's the function, which is typed more simply:

```
// actions without payloads only accept one parameter
function actionCreator<K extends ActionsWithoutPayloads>(
  type: K): Action<K>;

// actions with payloads require two parameters
function actionCreator<K extends keyof ActionPayloads>(
  type: K, payload: ActionPayloads[K]): Action<K>;

// same impl as before
function actionCreator(type: any, payload?: any) {
  return (typeof payload === 'undefined') ? { type } : { type, payload }
}
```

And let's make sure it works:

```
declare const resp: Response;

// no errors
const created = actionCreator(ActionTypes.created, resp); // Created
const deleted = actionCreator(ActionTypes.deleted); // Deleted
const okayDeleted = actionCreator('ns/deleted'); // okay this time

// errors
const badCreated = actionCreator(ActionTypes.created); // missing payload
const badDeleted = actionCreator(ActionTypes.deleted, "payload?!"); // unexpected payload
```

---

Whew!  Hope that helps; good luck.